# Pass 2D vector of doubles to function as **double

Tags: c++, stl

It is possible to pass 1D vector to a function as follows:

```
#include <vector>

void f(double *vec) {
    // do stuff..
}

int main() {
   std::vector<double> vec = {1,2,3};
   f(&vec[0]);
}
```

Is there any equivalent for passing `vector<vector<double>>` to `f(double **vec)`?

I'm joining two pieces of code together and it would be cumbersome to rewrite whole code to use either vectors or arrays.

Comment: You cannot view/interpret a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` as `T**`. that requires some transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a pointer to an element of `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` into a function accepting `double**` because the type of those elements is `std::vector<double>` and not `double*`. You would have to transform it into a `std::vector<double*>` to do the same.